# Is ghci super slow?

Tags: haskell

The following Haskell program for finding all perfect numbers below a given limit takes excecutes in about 5-10 seconds in ghci on my computer with n=10000:

```hs
 perf :: Int -> Bool 

 perf n = sum [d | d<-[1..div n 2], mod n d==0] == n 

 perfects :: Int -> [Int]

 perfects l = [n | n<-[1..l], perf n ]
```

Why is the excecution so slow?

Comment: The algorithm is quadratic, you should check this in a more efficient manner.

Comment: You can let `perf` run in *O(sqrt n)* time by enumerating with `d <- [1 ..  √ n]`. If `d*d` is not `n`, then count that `d` and `n/2`. Each divisor has a *co-divisor*. You thus can speed up the algorithm effetively.

Comment: See for example the Python implementation that works with the same trick: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-number/

Comment: You can use a fast prime factorization algorithm and construct all composite factors from those.

Comment: ...and since nobody else seems willing to say it: yes, ghci is super slow. Use `ghc -O2` when speed matters.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that you use to check if an item is a *perfect number* takes linear time, so that means that your `perfects` takes quadratic time.

You can improve the algorithm that checks if the item is a perfect number by only enumerating up to and including the square root. If we find a divisor `i` for `n`, we know that `n/i` is a divisor as well. We can thus implement this as:

```
perf :: Int -> Bool 
perf n = sum [ withco l | l <- ls, mod n l == 0 ] == n - 1
    where ls = takeWhile ((n >=) . (^2)) [ 2 .. ]
          withco i
              | i*i == n = i
              | otherwise = i + div n i
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution! However, is it not to be expected that an O(n^2) algortithm with input n=10000 should run almost instantaneously on a modern computer?

Comment: @Linderh: not without optimizations like Haskell's list fusion. If you compile it with `-O3` and then run it with `time`, I got for the quadratic solution 270ms, and for the O(n sqrt n) solution 9.55ms (including print time, etc.)

Comment: In 'GHCi' the 'i' stands for interactive/interpreter. "modern computer"s and even older computers expect to run compiled code, where the compiler can apply optimisations. (And there's many options for optimising in GHC -- for _compiled_ code.)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for GHC, [`-O3` is the same as `-O2`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--O%E2%9F%A8n%E2%9F%A9) (and `-O9001` for that matter). Suggesting to use `-O3` might lead people to think that there is a difference.